# Exoplayer Notification Image Addition

Tags: notifications, exoplayer

I am using PlayerNotificationManager in exoplayer.

Please let us all know the followings...

```
How to set custom image in Exoplayer Notification with action handler.
How to set subtext in Exoplayer Notification.
Will be of great help. Thank you.
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do that when you create your `MediaDescriptionAdapter`:

In the code below, `trackTitle`, `trackSubtitle` and `imageUri` are the data to show in the Notification.

The image is loaded asynchronously with Glide and the notification image is updated in the `callBack`.

Hope it helps! Regards from BR!

```
    private fun getMediaDescriptionAdapter(
        trackTitle: String,
        trackSubtitle: String
    ): PlayerNotificationManager.MediaDescriptionAdapter {
        return object : PlayerNotificationManager.MediaDescriptionAdapter {
            override fun createCurrentContentIntent(player: Player?): PendingIntent? {
                val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
                return PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    applicationContext,
                    0,
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                )
            }

            override fun getCurrentContentText(player: Player?): String? {
                return trackSubtitle
            }

            override fun getCurrentContentTitle(player: Player?): String {
                return trackTitle
            }

            override fun getCurrentLargeIcon(
                player: Player?,
                callback: PlayerNotificationManager.BitmapCallback?
            ): Bitmap? {

                if (trackPlaybackState.imageUri == null) return null

                // load the media image asyncronously
                val thread = Thread {
                    try {
                        val uri = Uri.parse(trackPlaybackState.imageUri.toString())
                        val bitmap = Glide.with(applicationContext)
                            .asBitmap()
                            .load(uri)
                            .submit().get()

                        trackImage = bitmap
                        callback?.onBitmap(bitmap)
                    } catch (e: ExecutionException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
                thread.start()

                return trackImage
            }
        }
    }
```